# Create a sorted Set while using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a **User** class with **name, type and age** and then a long list of these users are my input `List<User> users = db.getUsers();`.

I am trying to create a set of all unique users from this, but the problem is I am looking for sorting them based on the **age** also. I have currently used-

```
Set<User> set = users.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

How to sort this set at the same time as well, any idea?

Comment: How do you define uniqueness?

Comment: @Ravindra A User is duplicate as it has all of the attributes same as another user.

Comment: Have you overriden the `hashCode` and `equals` methods in `User`?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner yes, we have it implemented.

Comment: Note that both tasks (filtering by uniqueness and sorting by age) could be done by the database. This might even be faster depending on your scenario (using indices on the db, give the optimizer something to work with and avoiding duplicates on the network). You might even consider a unique constraint on the db.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to speak of order within a non sorted set.  You should be using something like `TreeSet` if you want a set ordered by age.

```
Comparator<User> byAge = Comparator.comparingInt(User::getAge);

Supplier<TreeSet<User>> user = () -> new TreeSet<User>(byAge);

TreeSet<User> userSet = users.stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(user));
```

If the above code be ugly to you, you could also just add your current set of users to a `TreeSet`, but there would be one more copy step.

The main difference between using a `TreeSet` and a `LinkedHashSet` has to do with maintaining sorting order.  With a `TreeSet`, when adding new users, the sorting would be maintained.  With a `LinkedHashSet`, adding new users might break the sort order by age, because `LinkedHashSet` only maintains insertion order.

**Edit:**

Based on the comments by @Federico below, a `TreeSet` actual would use its comparator to determine equality of `User` objects.  If you wanted to first remove all duplicate users by means of the `equals()` method, then we can first add all users to a `HashSet`, and then use the above approach to add them to a `TreeSet`.

```
Set<User> set = new HashSet<>(users);   // remove duplicates via equals
TreeSet<User> userSet = set.stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(user));
```

Comment: Why do we use `TreeSet` here and not a `LinkedHashSet` in other answer?

Comment: @Mani It depends on what you want.  A `TreeSet` is a sorted set, meaning if you iterate it, you will see the output sorted according to age.  `LinkedHashSet` is a set with a linked list running through it.  It maintains insertion order, so if you insert according to age, it will appear sorted.  The big difference is that my answer will remain sorted when adding new users, whereas the `LinkedHashSet` answer will not.

Comment: Further, a `TreeSet` knows that it is sorted according to a particular order and will report that, if asked. It also offers operation based on that knowledge, e.g. you can ask for a subset of all elements smaller than a particular reference value or ask for the next bigger or smaller element of an absent value, etc. By the way, you don’t need to use intermediate variables here, `TreeSet<User> users = users.stream() .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt( User::getAge))));` works too.

Comment: @Holger Agreed, but maybe the way I wrote it might be easier to read :-)

Comment: That’s a matter of style and I wouldn’t dare to discuss style… It’s just a small addition and the readers may decide themselves.

Comment: The problem I see with this answer is that it defines uniqueness as per the age of each user. So if 2 users have the same age, only one of them will be added to the `TreeSet`. This seems wrong to me. (Maybe the question was edited after you posted this answer?)

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't `User#equals` determine what is unique with regard to the set?  The age filed is only being used to sort those unique users.

Comment: Hi @Tim. My understanding is that in `TreeSet`, uniqueness is determined by the comparator provided in the constructor (or by the `Comparable.compareTo` method of the elements). So, when the comparison returns `0`, the elements are considered equal, so only one of them will remain in the set.

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html): `the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal`.

Answer (score 24):

You can possibly `sort` while streaming and collect to a `Set`.

Something like:

```
Set<User> finalList = users.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(User::getAge)) // sort while streaming
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)); 
        // note collecting to a set that maintains the order
```

Do note, that your object `User` should be comparable for that. i.e. has overriden `equals` and `hashCode`.

***Side note***: Your existing code could be simplified as:

```
Set<User> users = new HashSet<>(users);
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way of doing it assuming you have `equals` and `hashcode` methods implemented in the User class properly.

```
Set<User> uniqueUsers = new HashSet<>(users);
Set<User> sortedUniqueUsers = uniqueUsers.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(User::getAge))
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
```

Comment: Previous example with what `uniqueUsers` could be was much clear IMHO.

Comment: this exact example did not work to generate a sorted final set
when I just update it with -->.  Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)
it worked.

Answer (score 2):

```java
TreeSet<String> treeSet =
                List.<String>of().stream()
                                 .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```

Comment: How is this *sorting them based on the **age** also*?

Answer (score 1):

Use Comparator on [stream().sorted()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-) method

```
Set<User> set = users.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(User::getAge)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
```

And implement Comparable in User class

```
class User implements Comparable<User>{
```

and add compareTo method

```
@Override
public int compareTo(User ob) {
    return age-ob.getAge();
}
```

As @nullpointer and @Ravindra pointed, I have missed adding Collection( like TreeSet or LinkedHashSet)

Comment: The sorted order isn't maintained when you do a `Collectors.toSet()` after comparing in that `sort`.

Comment: But the set will distort the order. It is a hash based collection.

Comment: @nullpointer Thanks for pointing out. I have corrected my answer

Comment: @RavindraRanwala Thanks for pointing out. I have added the collection

Comment: Why do we use `TreeSet` here and not a `LinkedHashSet` in other answer?

Comment: @Mani You can use LinkedHashSet as well, which keeps the insertion order 
(After stream().sorted(), you keep inserting user object in a sorted way). So you get a sorted set. As you said, we don't need TreeSet since I'm already using stream comparator by Age(which is like comparing twice). I agree with you