# How to filter the age while grouping in map with list

Tags: java, filter, java-stream, grouping, java-10

Similar to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845355/create-a-sorted-set-while-using-streams), the **User** objects I have are these

```
new User("ayush","admin",23)
new User("ashish","guest",19) 
new User("ashish","admin",20) 
new User("garima","guest",29)
new User("garima","super",45)
new User("garima","guest",19)
```

Now I am trying to get the name to varying ages trend for these users. But I need to filter them above a `threshold` age. I could get the trend using

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> userNameAndAgeTrend = users.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(user-> user.getName(), Collectors.mapping(u-> u.getAge(), toList())));
```

this gives me `{ashish=[19, 20], garima=[29, 45, 19], ayush=[23]}`. But I am unable to filter the List properly using threshold for example **21 years** in my situation using such grouping. Can someone please help?

Also, using `.filter(user -> user.getAge() > 21)` gives no mapping for ashish, which is what I want to store too. I can use Java10 installed on my machine and trying the suggested solutions.

Answer (score 9):

#### [`Stream.filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate))

You could use `filter` as

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> userNameAndAgeTrend = users.stream()
        .filter(a -> a.getAge() > 21) // only above 21
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getName, Collectors.mapping(User::getAge, Collectors.toList())));
```

As confirmed by you in comments, this would give you as output

> ```
> {garima=[29, 45], ayush=[23]}
> ```

---

#### [`Collectors.filtering`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#filtering(java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.stream.Collector))

If you're looking for all the names, you could also use `Collectors.filtering` since [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9) which explicitly calls out a similar behavior (formatting mine) :

> Using a **`filtering`** collector as shown above *would result in a mapping
>   from that department to an empty Set*.
>
> If a stream **`filter()`** operation
>   were done instead, *there would be no mapping for that department at
>   all*.

Its usage should look something like:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> userNameAndAgeTrend = users.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getName, Collectors.mapping(User::getAge, 
                        Collectors.filtering(age -> age > 21, Collectors.toList()))));
```

and the output now would be

> ```
> {ashish=[], garima=[29, 45], ayush=[23]}
> ```

Comment: Using this I get `{garima=[29, 45], ayush=[23]}`, but I wanted the user "ashish" as well with no trends.

Comment: @Mani if you could update to Java9 you could use an inbuilt JDK utility for it or else probably implement your own. Aside: I would suggest making that as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 5):

if you want to `filter` **before** grouping:

```
users.stream()
     .filter(u -> u.getAge() > 21) //<--- apply the filter operation
     ...
```

`filter` is an intermediate operation which enables one to "keep the elements that satisfy the provided predicate" and exclude others that don't.

So, after the `filter` operation you have a new stream consisting of only the elements that pass the provided predicate. in this case only users where their age is older than 21.

---

if you want to `filter` **after** grouping (not to be confused with `filter` in a stream, this is a little different)

the `filtering` collector as of JDK9:

```
users.stream()
     .collect(groupingBy(User::getName, 
            filtering(u -> u.getAge() > 21, 
                   mapping(User::getAge, toList()))));
```

see, the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48273090/how-to-apply-filtering-on-groupby-in-java-streams) for a JDK8 implementation.

With stream’s `filter` above, the values are filtered first and then it’s grouped. in other words, after filtering we have "no trace" of them.

However, with the `filtering` collector as of `JDK9` we can maintain a trace.

Comment: Using this I get `{garima=[29, 45], ayush=[23]}`, but I wanted the user "ashish" as well with no trends.

Comment: @Mani maybe you're after the `filtering` collector as of jdk9?

Comment: Let me try filtering. Stupid me, forgot to update in question, I can use until Java 10 installed on my laptop.

Comment: Thank you, the filtering works as you all pointed. Just see a difference in sequence of call from the other answer here, I hope that doesn't matter much. They both run similarily for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `.filter()` operation before the `.collect()` one

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> userNameAndAgeTrend = 
                      users.stream()
                           .filter(user -> user.getAge() > 21)
                           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(user-> user.getName(), Collectors.mapping(u-> u.getAge(), toList())));
```

Comment: Using this I get `{garima=[29, 45], ayush=[23]}`, but I wanted the user "ashish" as well with no trends.

Comment: @Mani what did you mean by "with no trends"?

Comment: There should be mapping with empty list for age of ashish for the current input, like ashish=[] @Andrew

Comment: @Mani seems like you're after `users.stream()
                        .collect(groupingBy(User::getName, 
                                filtering(u -> u.getAge() > 21, 
                                        mapping(User::getAge, toList()))));`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the other solutions works for me.