# How do I create two different compliementary lists using same input

Tags: java, java-stream

In my previous question - [How to filter the age while grouping in map with list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53859947/how-to-filter-the-age-while-grouping-in-map-with-list) I was able to find the name to age groups using `List<User> users`. Now I am trying to find the different **User groups** from ages according to the threshold. I tried this

```
List<User> userAboveThreshold = users.stream().filter(u -> u.getAge() > 21).collect(toList());
List<User> userBelowThreshold = users.stream().filter(u -> u.getAge() <= 21).collect(toList());
```

This time it works I can see using

```
userAboveThreshold.forEach(u -> System.out.println(u.getName() + " " + u.getAge()));
userBelowThreshold.forEach(u -> System.out.println(u.getName() + " " + u.getAge()));
```

But I have to access the **users** list again to find the complimentary list. Can this not be done simpler?

Answer (score 7):

You're after the `partitioningBy` collector:

```
Map<Boolean, List<User>> result = 
             users.stream().collect(partitioningBy(u -> u.getAge() > 21));
```

Then use it as follows:

```
List<User> userAboveThreshold = result.get(true);
List<User> userBelowThreshold = result.get(false);
```

Comment: @Mani well you should also know that internally it uses a specialized map with two keys only, faster look-up then a `HashMap` for example

Answer (score 5):

#### [`List.removeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection))

You can use `removeAll` to obtain the complimentary list.

```
List<User> userBelowThreshold = new ArrayList<>(users); // initiated with 'users'
userBelowThreshold.removeAll(userAboveThreshold);
```

*Note*: This would require overridden `equals` and `hashCode` implementation for `User`.

---

#### [`Collectors.partitioningBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy(java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.stream.Collector))

On the other hand, if you further want to iterate over the complete `users` list *just once*, you can use `Collectors.partitioningBy` as:

```
Map<Boolean, List<User>> userAgeMap = users.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(user -> user.getAge() > 21, Collectors.toList()));
List<User> userAboveThreshold = userAgeMap.get(Boolean.TRUE);
List<User> userBelowThreshold = userAgeMap.get(Boolean.FALSE);
```

Comment: For those concerned about the cost of using a map here, worry not, `Collectors.partitioningBy` returns a [custom map class](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#l1540) that stores the 2 partitions (holding the the `true` and `false` member) directly inline.