# How to extract values from a list of class objects, remove the duplicates and sort alphabetically?

Tags: java, duplicates, java-stream, treeset, collectors

I have a class *Tag* in java

```
public class Tag {
    private int excerptID;
    private String description;
    }
```

and I am extracting descriptions from a list of Tag objects *rawTags* to a set (I need to remove duplicate values):

```
Set<String> tags = rawTags.stream().map(Tag::getDescription).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

but I also want to have the resulting set (or list of unique descriptions) alphabetically ordered. Is there a way how to use TreeSet directly with Collectors or what would be the easiest way how to extract, remove duplicates and order alphabetically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a sorted Set while using streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845355/create-a-sorted-set-while-using-streams)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Collectors.toCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection(java.util.function.Supplier)) and pass method reference to `TreeSet` constructor:

```
Set<String> tags = rawTags.stream() //or you can assign to TreeSet directly
    .map(Tag::getDescription)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```

and in case you wanted to pass custom comparator :

```
.collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)));
```

Comment: Nice explanation. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tag tag1 = new Tag(1,"9a");
        Tag tag2 = new Tag(2,"32");
        Tag tag3 = new Tag(3,"4c");
        Tag tag4 = new Tag(4,"1d");

        List<Tag> rawTags = new ArrayList<>();
        rawTags.add(tag1);rawTags.add(tag2);rawTags.add(tag3);rawTags.add(tag4);
        Set<String> tags = rawTags.stream().map(Tag::getDescription).collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
        System.out.print(tags);
    }
```